# How to install in Virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox

I can't get Elemetary to install on a virtual machine in Virtualbox. Somehow it doesn't want to load the .iso

Answer (score 1):

I just recently installed Elementary in Virtualbox without an issue.  Can you share a bit more information?

Where in the process are you getting stuck?

If you use the Wizard to create the machine, you may have to go in and designate the ISO to run after the machine has been made.

You can go into settings, and select your ISO the first time you attempt to run the Machine.
[image]

Click that little drop down and you'll be able to browse to where you've saved your ISO file.  Then try to run the machine again after you've saved your settings.

Give that a try.